# Android Studio cannot import com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm having a problem that every once in a while, suddenly I get a gradle error of:
`No such property: config for class: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin` that I don't know how to solve (and don't know what made it disappear on the previous times it happened to me).

It seems like the problem is that the Android Studio doesn't recognise `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin` because I get `cannot resolve symbol` on the `com.google` part (Inside build.gradle(:app)).

I've already watch more than 20 other questions regarding this issue, all of them suggest the same thing - updating the `com.google.gms:google-services` or adding `jcenter()` In addition to Maven, but these are already updated in my code.

Also tried :

- `Invalidate Caches/Restart`
- Updating gradle plugin
- Delete and re-install `Google play services`, `Android SDK Build-Tools`, `Android SDK Platforms-Tools` & `Android SDK Tools` SDKs in the SDK manager
- update Android Studio to latest version

I'm pretty lost here, any help please?

My Build.gradle(:Project) :

```
        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix, change your app's `build.gradle` from the following:

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin = true
```

To:

```
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

There's some further discussion here:
https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/36

Comment: My build failed due to the following line: 

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

Replacing it with googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android studio SDK Manager and update or install google play services.
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, already did that and it didn't help :/

Answer (score 0):

version classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' worked to me